# Do Andy and Riley live in the same world?

Tags: pixar, inside-out, toy-story

Barring [large scale theories about interconnected universes](http://www.pixartheory.com/), and looking at a slightly more realistic point of view, can we say that Andy from *Toy Story* and Riley from *Inside Out* live in the same "world"?

Both seem to live in relatively non-fantastical representation of the world (talking toys and inner voices notwithstanding — which neither know about).

Given that Pixar leaves clues in their movies, can we tell if Andy and Riley could meet?

In order of preferred answers, I'd prefer first-order relations between films so evidence of shared elements between Toy Story and Inside Out:

For example:

- Both Andy and Riley move house and eat pizza, did they use the same mover or eat the same pizza?
- Riley drove through the midwest, near landscape similar to where Lotso was left.

I'll also accept answers where another Pixar movie is used for the connection, for example:

- Did Andy and Rileys parents both shop at Buy 'n' Large (from Wall-E)?
- Did Andy and Rileys parents both own a copy of Chef Auguste Gusteau's book "Anyone Can Cook" (from Ratatouille)?

Comment: Is this on-topic? Inside Out doesn't seem like Sci Fi or Fantasy to me (it's clear the little dudes inside people's minds are supposed to be metaphors for actual emotions, and we're not supposed to believe this is anything but the real world).

Comment: Given that this question is *also* about *Toy Story*, which is clearly fantasy, I think that pushes it back squarely into "on-topic" territory, and I'm retracting my VTC.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield That's a good point. So is this actually a question about Toy Story? :)

Comment: @AndresF. - The mob have spoken. Inside-Out is off-topic but since this question is (50%) about Toy Story, I'm going to leave it here.

Comment: @Richard Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 22):

Both films appear to be set in the same geographical region; The fictional "[Tri-County](http://pixar.wikia.com/Tri-County_International_Airport)" area

[image]

and they both appear to have food items from the same Chinese restaurant seen in [Toy Story 2](http://pixar.wikia.com/Chinese_Food_Box?file=ToyChinese.png)

[image]

You could also note that the tech seen in the films (Skype, eBay, internet, flat-screen TVs) would seem to localise the films sometime between the late 1990s and the present day so Andy and Riley are almost certainly contemporaries, albeit she appears to be at least 6+ years younger based on the phones and computers seen in the films.

Comment: in the US, pretty much every chinese take-out joint uses the same box. i wouldn't put any stock in those matching.

Comment: @phantom42 - That may well be true, but the [one in the pixar films](http://pixar.wikia.com/Chinese_Food_Box) is not identical to the [Fold-Pak](http://everythinghapa.com/archives/474) ones seen across the States.

Comment: Slightly younger? More like, 6+ years younger. In Toy Story 3, Andy, a 17-year-old, goes to university and is seen with a flip phone. In Inside Out, Riley, an 11-year-old, already has a smartphone.

Comment: @Richard - In my experience, almost every Chinese take out place has it's own logo printed on the boxes.  A pagoda is one of the more common designs.  However, it does appear that Pixar has deliberately chosen to use the same box in several movies.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - Pixar have established that "Tri-county" is an actual place, not merely a description of an area.

Comment: Yes, but is it the name of a single county (and the *same* one every time), or just a name they picked (like Springfield) because it's a common and non-specific name for a metro area consisting of three separate counties (like [Tri-County, Oregon](http://www.tri-countychamber.com/) or [Tri-County, Florida](https://plus.google.com/112251590251920171767/about?gl=us&hl=en))

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - It's not clear. In the absence of any proof to the contrary, I think we can assume it's a fictional place called Tri-County and that each film is set in the same place.

Answer (score 20):

Yes. Not only do they live in the same world, they also somehow know Carl and Ellie from *Up.*

In *Toy Story 3*, Andy has a postcard from the couple.

[image: *Toy Story* postcard]

In *Inside Out*, Riley [apparently](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/inside-out-easter-eggs-references-jokes-pixar-122544119257.html) [has](http://whatculture.com/film/inside-out-22-easter-eggs-in-jokes-and-references-you-need-to-see.php/2) [very](http://www.slashfilm.com/inside-out-easter-eggs/) hazy memories of them.

Additionally, the same playground equipment company appears to exist in each world.

[image: Playground equipment]

Comment: Good finds. Not conclusive, but a nice crossover.